# Running VBA macros using Python, but wait between macros

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to run VBA macros in several workbooks, but I would like to have the macros run sequentially. So far, I figured out how to run the macros using PyWin32, but the macros do not run in series. I tried to get it to work by using subprocess like so:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.join(subdir,file))
    p = subprocess.Popen(["xl.Application.Run(\"macro1\")"])
    p.wait()
    p = subprocess.Popen(["xl.Application.Run(\"macro2\")"])
    p.wait()
```

but I came across an error which said: "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Am I using the Popen object wrong? Is there an alternative solution this problem? I am quite new to Python so any answer is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're getting that error because there is no program called `xl.Application.Run("macro1")` installed on your system. Yes, you are using `Popen` wrong. It isn't for this. Why are you using it? Why aren't you just doing `xl.Application.Run("macro1")`?

Comment: That's what I used at first, but the script ran the macros concurrently, not in series. I was under the impression that Popen was used to have the processes "wait" for others to finish.

Comment: Well, I mean, yes, you can use the `Popen.wait()` method to wait for the subprocess to finish, but to do that you have to start the subprocess using `Popen` to begin with. What you give `Popen` is the command line you use to start the process, not a Python command. You have already started the process using PyWin32 so...